# How to properly iterate and parse nested objects in javascript with or without lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

I'm currently working on a service that returns the following payload:

```
{
  "account1": {
    "app1": {
      "status": "Online",
      "comments": "blah blah",
      "events": [
        {
          "date": "some date",
          "generated_by": "some user"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "account2": {
    "app1": {
      "status": "Offline",
      "comments": "blah blah bleh",
      "events": [
        {
          "date": "some date",
          "generated_by": "some user"
        }
      ]
    },
    "app2": {
      "status": "Online",
      "comments": "blah blah",
      "events": [
        {
          "date": "some date",
          "generated_by": "some user"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I'm trying to render a table with the following fields:

```
-------------------------------
Application | Account  | Status
-------------------------------
app1        | account1 | Online
app1        | account2 | Offline
app2        | account2 | Online
```

Normally this would be easy to do if my payload would be something like a list of objects but I'm kinda stuck here.

I tried to normalize this payload by extracting each of the fields and creating a new payload by doing something like the following:

```
const extractAccountNumber = Object.values(payload).map(account => ({account: account}))
```

which would return:

```
[
  {
    "account": "account1"
  },
  {
    "account": "account2"
  }
]
```

I wanted to move on to app name the same way and once I get all my fields I would merge the payload. This has proven to be super cumbersome and I'm sure there is a better, more efficient way to achieve this which I'm probably missing. Any feedback would help me a ton to understand how this can be achieved using javascript with or without lodash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterating by first level and then by second level:

```js
table = [];
for (accountName in apiResponse) {
    account = apiResponse[accountName];
    for (appName in account) {
        app = account[appName];
        table.push({
            application: appName,
            account: accountName,
            status: app.status,
        });
    }
}
```

Then table is something like this:

```json
[
    {
        "application": "app1",
        "account": "account1",
        "status": "Online"
    },
    {
        "application": "app1",
        "account": "account2",
        "status": "Offline"
    },
    {
        "application": "app2",
        "account": "account2",
        "status": "Online"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Can try something like

```
Object.entries(o).map(([accountName, value]) => ({ 
    account: accountName,
    apps: Object.entries(value)
        .map(([appName, value]) => ({name: appName, ...value }))
}))
```

Not sure about structure. Where to put app1 from account2 in that table?

Comment: Yeah, I've tried this before. Unfortunately that's another headscratcher for me